# Unable to download the form data using javascript. Looking for distinct class and sleecting the [i]th component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to download the form data which the user enters through a utility which I have built on HTML and Node.js. I have defined a dictionary data where I am capturing the data and adding it to the payload in a particular format.
I am using querySelectorAll to look for the distinct classes and then populating those fields in my data section accordingly. Although the same data is getting replicated in both sections A and B parts of the data(as shown in the code). Can anyone help me solve this issue as the fields for A and B sections are different and I need to capture both of them. Attaching the code to replicate the issue and also the html part of the code.
For example, While I attempted to create a class MC_IP and looked for it using queryselector I am getting the error 'Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'.

JS Part

```js
    let paylod=''
    const Ctids = document.querySelectorAll('.CONTROLLER_ID');
    const mcIps = document.querySelectorAll('.mc_ip');
    const MCIP = document.querySelectorAll('.MC_IP');
    const mcNetmasks = document.querySelectorAll('.Netmask_IP');
    const mcGateways = document.querySelectorAll('.Gateway_IP');
    const mc = document.querySelectorAll('.RBOD_MC');
    const ec = document.querySelectorAll('.RBOD_EC');
    const fu = document.querySelectorAll('.RBOD_FU');
    const sc = document.querySelectorAll('.RBOD_SC');

    const step = oForm.chassis.value;

        let payload = '';
        //Creating the data elements to be cpatured in the downloaded yaml file 

        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
const data = {" PDU:": {"PDU_IP":['     PDU_IP',' '+ oForm.ip.value,"   #PDU IP",'  '+'\n'],
          "PDU_LEFT":['     PDU_LEFT',[oForm.lo.value]," # left_outlet(s) ",'   '+'\n'],
          "PDU_RIGHT":['        PDU_RIGHT',[oForm.ro.value]," # right_outlet(s) ", '    '+'\n']
        },  
        "   \n  Controller: # Controller settings ": {  

            "Controller_ID#1": ["       -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD"],
                "Netmask IP_A":["           MC_IP",' '+mcIps[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],
                "MC_Netmask_A": ["          MC_Netmask",' '+mcNetmasks[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
                'MC_Gateway_A':['           MC_Gateway',' '+mcGateways[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
                'MC_A': ['          MC',' '+mc[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
                'SC_A':['           SC',' '+sc[i+1].value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
                'FU_A':['           FU',' '+fu[i+1].value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
                'EC_A':["           EC",' '+ec[i+1].value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',''+'\n'],
                'Controller_ID#2': ["           ID",' '+Ctids[i+1].value,"  #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n'],       
            "Controller_ID#3": ['\n'+"      -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD"],
                "Netmask IP_B":["           MC_IP",' '+MCIP[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],
                "MC_Netmask_B": ["          MC_Netmask",' '+mcNetmasks[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
                'MC_Gateway_B':['           MC_Gateway',' '+mcGateways[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
                'MC_B': ['          MC',' '+mc[i+1].value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
                'SC_B':['           SC',' '+sc[i+1].value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
                'FU_B':['           FU',' '+fu[i+1].value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
                'EC_B':["           EC",' '+ec[i+1].value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',''+'\n'],
                'Controller_ID#4': ["           ID",' '+Ctids[i+1].value,"  #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n'],   
        }
      };
      addToPayload(data, '' );
}
```

```html
<div id="tab1"  class="tabcontent">
<h4>Chasis 1 Details</h4>
<div id="extra" style="display:hidden;">

<h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
  <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
  <select class="CONTROLLER_ID" id='Controller_ID1' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='A'>A </select>
  <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text' name='extra_ip1' id='mc_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
  <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text' id='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
  <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text' id='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
  <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' id='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' id='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' id='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' id='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
  <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
  <select class="CONTROLLER_ID" id='Controller_ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
  <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba1"  placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='MC_IP_B'>MC_IP:</label><input class="MCIP" type='text'  id='mcip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
  <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text'  id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
  <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text'  id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
  <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the wrong index to get elements from your array of HTML elements.  When you try and get the value from an element in the array, you are using `mc[i+1].value` instead of `mc[i].value` (remember arrays in JS start from 0).

When you are using `mc[i+1]` to get an element from the array, your index exceeds the maximum index of the array of HTML elements so `undefined` is returned.

So changing all your `[x+1]` to `[x]` should resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for the response but I had to change the [i] to [i+1] as it was running only 0th iteration and was not going to the [1]st. It is working fine with i+1. Undefined is returned for MCIP the one in front of 'Netmask IP_B' i.e. the section where Controller B additional details need to be populated. Can you tell why is that happening?

Comment: That's because your classes are different between the two MCIP fields.  The one has the class "MCIP" and the other "mc_ip"

Comment: Yes that's because I want to cpature the data of the second MC_IP field seperately. Otherwise with the same class name its just replicating the value of the Controller A MC_IP into Controller B MC_IP. Is there any way I can capture both the values of Controller A and Controller, its for all the fields out there including MC_IP

Comment: Why do you never select the field with the class "MCIP" in your script? You're only selecting ".mc_ip" and ".MC_IP"

Comment: I did that and now its showing that mcIps is undefined :\